# Как воспроизвести звук определенной частоты?

Tags: c#, .net, directx

Мне нужно написать такой код который на правый канал (правая колонка) посылал бы звук одной частоты а на левый другой.

Хочу реализовать под .NET с помощью DirectSound, пишу на C#.

Подскажите какие-нибудь методы, функции, классы из библиотек DirectX (или другие если знаете) которые позволяют работать со звуком на низком уровне, то есть так чтобы можно было задавать частоту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый вариант. Синтезировать звук в какой-либо программе по обработке звука и записать в файл, затем воспроизвести:

```
SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer();

sp.SoundLocation = @"beep.wav";
sp.Play();
```

Второй вариант. Использовать динамик

```
// Пищит в течение одной секунды с частотой 1кГц
Console.Beep(1000, 1000);
```

Третий вариант. Для .NET существует хорошая библиотека по работе со звуком: [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/). [Используя ее](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/10/playback-of-sine-wave-in-naudio.html)

```
var sineWaveProvider = new SineWaveProvider32();

sineWaveProvider.SetWaveFormat(16000, 1); // 16kHz mono
sineWaveProvider.Frequency = 1000;
sineWaveProvider.Amplitude = 0.25f;
waveOut = new WaveOut();
waveOut.Init(sineWaveProvider);
waveOut.Play();
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Третьй вариант как раз для меня. Пока вы ответили сделал кое что с secondarybuffer, но вышло слишком коряво.